# AIR and Google Maps Javascript V3 Street View

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, air, google-street-view

I'm getting super crazy with an `SWF`, ran by `Windows 7 Adobe AIR runtime`, and `Google Maps Javascript V3` embedded into a super-basic `html` page.

The `SWF` just load the latter `html` and shows the map.

Navigation through the classics `2d map` works perfectly but, when the `street view` mode starts, `air` generate tons of javascript errors. 
The same `html`, loaded by any browser, works flawlessly.

I created a super simple `SWF` as proof of concept. This is the super minimal `mxml` source code:

```
<mx:WindowedApplication
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    creationComplete="init();"
>
    <mx:UIComponent
        id="bxMap"
        width="100%" height="100%"
    />

    <mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

    private var _browser:HTMLLoader;
    private var _sprite:Sprite;

    private function init():void {

        _browser = new HTMLLoader();
        _browser.width = bxMap.width;
        _browser.height = bxMap.height;
        _sprite = new Sprite();

        _browser.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, map_Ready);
        _browser.load(new URLRequest("https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-simple?hl=it"));
    }

    private function map_Ready(event:Event):void {

        _sprite.addChild(_browser);
        bxMap.addChild(_sprite);

    }

    ]]>
    </mx:Script>

</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

As you can see, the html is taken from a google example, so it should not contain any kind of weird stuff... Anyway, i tried also super minimal html written by me and the same problem occours.

This is the typical javascript error catched by AIR console. Just move the mouse around in the street view to generate hundreds of error like this:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'a' [undefined] is not an object.
Hu at  : 2
 at  : 9
ag at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 25
 at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 24
lC at  : 13
 at  : 10
 at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 9
 at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 19
 at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 21
 at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 19
 at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 21
 at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 19
Fr at  : 73
 at  : 72
 at https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/it_it/mapfiles/api-3/14/3/main.js : 20
```

***Any idea about why this happens and how to get rid of it?***

I tried to notify this behaviour to google (at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/ ) but someone deleted my issue after just few minutes. No one told me WHY my issue had to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `HTMLLoader`. It's convenient, but it is not full-featured. Instead, switch to `StageWebView`, which is the recommended way for displaying most web content in AIR. You will have to deal with it not being in the Display List, but I can confirm it works. I built a Google Maps Flex component using it just last week to allow for Google Maps on mobile.

HTMLLoader uses the built in AIR Webkit render engine, which isn't a very complete engine and has issues with many things. StageWebView, on the other hand, uses the system's browser (Safari on OS X and iOS, IE on Windows, Chrome/Browser on Android) to render the content, which is generally far more reliable.

I can confirm that both my component (which actually generates an HTML page incorporating the Maps v3 API on-the-fly) and the link you provided work using StageWebView on Android, OS X, and iOS. I don't have a Windows computer to test on, but it should work there as well.

Comment: Josh, thank you for the response. I tried StageWebView like you suggested, but nothing has changed. Just to gather more infos, i tried to put a js alert into a test page outputting the version of rendering engine used. It's the same for both HTMLLoader and StageWebView ( a super-old webkit 533.19.4, used by Safari back in 2010 =\\\\\ ). Maybe AIR for iOS and Android uses a more recent version of webkit.

Comment: AIR for iOS and Android uses Safari and Chrome for those platforms. AIR or OS X uses Safari as well. I think I remember reading that Adobe switched from using IE to using a built in Webkit for Windows because of how poor IE was a few years ago. It does work on OS X, though. I think you may be out of luck here, unfortunately.

Comment: Just FYI I opened a feature request at adobe bugbase.
https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3630656

Hope something will change soon. Anyway thank you for your replies

Comment: Can we get your component?

Comment: @icemelt7 Sorry, I built it for a client. Can't release the code. That said, it is seriously just a `StageWebView` that loads a simple Google Maps API v3 page via a string I pass it that is populated via set variables. There is no logic to it at all, other than making it scroll with the page (which is a royal pain, but doable)